# Photon rotation

Tags: photons, quantum-spin, polarization

The rotation of a photon around an axis with orientation given by the vector n⃗  is the action representated by the operator $ U = e^{ i \theta \vec{n}. \vec{J} } $. But to get a clearer understanding of what that would mean in a specific case... $$ $$
Suppose  $ \vec{n} $ were parallel to  $ \vec{J} $ and that and the photon's direction of propagation is along $z$ and that at time $t = t_0$, the photon's electric field $ \vec{E} $ were pointing up along $y$ direction. $$ $$ Suppose now at $t_0$, the photon is 'rotated' about $ \vec{n} $  by an angle $ \Pi $, (180 degrees) what now are the directions of $ \vec{E} $ and  $ \vec{J} $ ?

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for equation rendering. The link has a detailed tutorial on how. Thanks.

Comment: "the photon's electric field"  The photon does not have an electric field, you are confusing it with the classical electromagnetic wave, which emerges from a large number of photons. this question and answers are relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90646/what-is-the-relation-between-electromagnetic-wave-and-photon

Comment: @anna if a photon doesn't have an associated electric field / electric vector, how can 2 photons have an electric field, how can 2,000,000,000 photons? where does the 'bunch' of photons get this electric field when none of the photons comprising that 'bunch' has any electric field?

Comment: @anna A photon does have an electric field associated with it, otherwise how can a single photon knock out a single electron via the photoelectric effect, and a single photon make a dot on a screen in a double-slit nterference experiment!

Comment: Bit lost. Isn't the $\vec J$ in $e^{i\theta\vec n\cdot\vec J}$ a vector *of angular momentum operators*? Does it make sense to talk about $\vec n$ being parallel to $\vec J$? And anna v has a point. The $\vec E$ field of a photon is no longer a vector field. It is a field of vector-valued *quantum observables*. For a single photon, $\vec E$ has such high uncertainty that "$\vec E$ pointing up along the $y$ direction" no longer makes sense. You need many photons to build up a coherent ("classical looking") state (in which the uncertainty in $\vec E$ becomes small)

Comment: @pete **Mainstream** particle physics standard model has the  photpn as a point particle with spin vector 1 and energy hnu, where nu is the frequency of the classical light many photons build up, The wavefunction of the photon is associated with the average E and B fields that they will built up in coherence, because the maxwell equation in a quantized form is used to calculate the wave function of the photon, see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604169

Comment: @pete the interactiions of the photon are calculated using the Feynman diagrams that can calculate the probability of interaction or decay. see diagram here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174051/show-that-a-photon-cannot-transmit-its-total-energy-to-a-free-electron-contradi/174084#174084